# Why does CSS effects appear only on JSP preview but not on the browser?

Tags: html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

Inside my Java EE app I created a jsp page as follows: I'm creating a table showing the flights in rows . The flights are inside "fList" List under the "flight_list" request attribute .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/css/styles.css"
    type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Flights</h1>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Airplane</th>
            <th>Seating</th>
            <th>Number of Pilotes</th>
            <th>Pilots names</th>
        </tr>    
        <%
            List<Flight> fList = (List<Flight>) request.getAttribute("flight_list");

            for (Integer i = 0; i < fList.size(); i++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=fList.get(i).getFlightOrigin()%></td>
            <td><%=fList.get(i).getFlightDestination()%></td>
            <td><%=fList.get(i).getFlightTime()%></td>
            <td><%=fList.get(i).getPrice()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

### And styles.css as follows

```
h1{
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}

table {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 115%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}
  th {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  td {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
```

Here you see my project structure

1. WebContent-->WEB-INF-->views-->flights-list.jsp
2. WebContent-->resources-->css-->styles.css

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xFHT.png)

CSS effects are seen only in eclipse

The CSS file is loaded only on the JSP preview tab . The problem is that they don't appear on the browser unless I put the css code inside `<style>...</styles> .`

Please help me to load the page correctly on my browser.

Comment: I think you *.css file is not loading properly.Please share structure of project.

Comment: Sanjay , please click on "Project Structure" to see the project structure and how the effects are working fine only in eclipse *.jsp .

Comment: Add This line in *.jsp file. <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Use below link  tag to load/include .css/.js file in jsp at header Part

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="resources/javascript/foo.js"></script>
    ---
</head>
```

or if you want to include third party css/js specify full path from  url:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="htts://..../foo.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="htts://..../foo.css"></script>
```